# Command to watch file changes and created files and folders

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I am working with Laravel Mix. Everything is working, and Laravel Mix is watching files. However, when I create a new file or folder, I get the following error.

> Unable to locate mix file

I want to know if there is any Webpack or Laravel Mix command that solves this problem so that I do not need to run the `npm run watch` command on the newly created file or folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are your only options...

```
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
```